# Flutter/Dart: Create a GridView where the first item is a unique grid item

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and Dart but I have a grid view on one of my screens and I want the first grid item to be a unique button that allows the user to add a student. You can see in the image below an example of what I am trying to accomplish. How do I create a unique view with the first item allowing a user to add a student?

[image]

**Grid Class:**

```
body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ProfileHeader(),
              ProfileViewSwitch(),
              ProfileSearch(),
              Flexible(
                //Below is the GridView used for each student in the class
                child: GridView(
                  //TODO convert to a builder for performance efficiency
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
                      .map(
                        (catData) => ImageItem(
                          catData.firstName,
                          catData.lastName,
                          catData.color,
                          catData.initials,
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    //maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**Image Item Class:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipOval(
                      child: Material(
                        color: color, // button color
                        child: InkWell(
                          //splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 80,
                            height: 80,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(initials,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 35)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      firstName,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      lastName,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result in two ways,

**Method 1:** Using `GridView,builder`, return your `Button` at index `0` - I'd recommend to using this method.

```
GridView.builder(
  //TODO convert to a builder for performance efficiency
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
  itemCount: DUMMY_CATEGORIES.length + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      );
    }
    final catData = DUMMY_CATEGORIES[i - 1];
    return ImageItem(
      catData.firstName,
      catData.lastName,
      catData.color,
      catData.initials,
    );
  },
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    //maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    childAspectRatio: 1,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  ),
)
```

**Method 2:** Concat a `null` or unique value in from and handle during `map`

```
GridView(
  //TODO convert to a builder for performance efficiency
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
  children: [null, ...DUMMY_CATEGORIES].map(
    (catData) {
      if (catData == null) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {},
        );
      }
      return ImageItem(
        catData.firstName,
        catData.lastName,
        catData.color,
        catData.initials,
      );
    },
  ).toList(),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    //maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    childAspectRatio: 1,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  ),
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Your solution was very simple and easy to implement. Thanks for the assistance!